How am I able to not have my data come in as a function for my code within R Time series analysis?
I am looking to create a code that brings in data from a csv file that is pasted below. I am trying to have all of the commodities compare to the MOM change to the inflation rate with diesel in all of the charts as well. Then measure the correlation between them to see if inflation is correlated to them.
enter image description here
Below is the code currently-
# Load necessary libraries
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# Read the data from the CSV file
data <- read_csv("commodities_inflation_data.csv", skip = 1)  # Skip the first row (header row)

# Extract the date columns from the header row
dates <- as.Date(names(data)[-1], format = "MOM %b %Y")

# Transpose the data so that commodities are in rows and dates are in columns
data <- t(data[-1])  # Transpose the data excluding the first column

# Convert to data frame
data <- as.data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(data) <- c("Commodity", dates)  # Rename columns

# Define the commodities of interest
commodities_of_interest <- c("Wheat", "Soybean", "Corn", "Ground_Beef", "Bacon", "Eggs", "Chicken")

# Plot each commodity against inflation and diesel separately
for (commodity in commodities_of_interest) {
  p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!sym(commodity))) +
geom_line(color = "blue") +
    geom_line(aes(y = Inflation), color = "red") +
    labs(title = paste("Monthly Percentage Change in", commodity, "vs. Inflation"),
     y = "Percentage Change",
     x = "Date") +
    theme_minimal()
  print(p1)

  p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!sym(commodity))) +
    geom_line(color = "blue") +
    geom_line(aes(y = Diesel), color = "green") +
    labs(title = paste("Monthly Percentage Change in", commodity, "vs. Diesel"),
         y = "Percentage Change",
         x = "Date") +
    theme_minimal()
  print(p2)
}

# Calculate correlation between inflation and commodities
correlation_with_inflation <- sapply(data[, commodities_of_interest], function(x) cor(x,         data$Inflation))

# Calculate correlation between inflation, diesel, and commodities
correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel <- sapply(data[, commodities_of_interest], function(x) cor(x,     cbind(data$Inflation, data$Diesel)))

# Print correlation results
print("Correlation between inflation and commodities:")
print(correlation_with_inflation)

print("Correlation between inflation, diesel, and commodities:")
print(correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel)`

This is what I got spit out to me
`> # Load necessary libraries
> library(readr)
> library(dplyr)
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

> library(ggplot2)
> # Read the data from the CSV file
> data <- read_csv("commodities_inflation_data.csv", skip = 1)  # Skip the first row (header row)
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘vroom’
> names(data) <- c("Commodity", dates)  # Rename columns
Error in names(data) <- c("Commodity", dates) : 
  names() applied to a non-vector
> # Define the commodities of interest
> commodities_of_interest <- c("Wheat", "Soybean", "Corn", "Ground_Beef", "Bacon", "Eggs", "Chicken")
> # Plot each commodity against inflation and diesel separately
> for (commodity in commodities_of_interest) {
+   p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!sym(commodity))) +
+     geom_line(color = "blue") +
+     geom_line(aes(y = Inflation), color = "red") +
+          y = "Percentage Change",
+          x = "Date") +
+     theme_minimal()
+   print(p1)
+   
+   p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!sym(commodity))) +
+     geom_line(color = "blue") +
+     geom_line(aes(y = Diesel), color = "green") +
+     labs(title = paste("Monthly Percentage Change in", commodity, "vs. Diesel"),
+          y = "Percentage Change",
+          x = "Date") +
+     theme_minimal()
+   print(p2)
+ }
Error in `ggplot()`:
! `data` cannot be a function.
ℹ Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()``
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> # Print correlation results
> print("Correlation between inflation and commodities:")
[1] "Correlation between inflation and commodities:"
> print(correlation_with_inflation)
Error in print(correlation_with_inflation) : 
  object 'correlation_with_inflation' not found
> print("Correlation between inflation, diesel, and commodities:")
[1] "Correlation between inflation, diesel, and commodities:"
> print(correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel)
Error in print(correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel) : 
  object 'correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel' not found


You've got many error messages. Fixing the first one (importing the csv file correctly) may fix them all. ... Try read.csv instead of read_csv.

Thank you for that and that was a mistake should have caught! However second line under the #convert to data frame the commodity is still having issues
